# Get windows 10 default like icons

Tags: c#, wpf, icons

I'm currently building a wpf application and am looking for a "generic" looking set of icons like they are used in windows explorer, they can be something between xp and 10 style as long as I have a consistent set of icons in .png format for functions like: new file, open, save, save as, send to, undo, redo, ...

Is there a way to use the windows internal once?
Or a way to get some from the internet?
I tried the [VS2015 Image Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246582.aspx) but the icons there have different resolutions and colors. I couldn't even find a pair for undo/redo with the same resolution/color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the list of dlls that you can get icons from on any windows OS:

**%systemroot%\system32\imageres.dll** - contains lots of icons, used almost everywhere in Windows 10. It has icons for different types of folders, hardware devices, actions, and so on.

**%systemroot%\system32\shell32.dll** - also has lots of icons used in various parts of Windows 10. Together with imageres.dll , shell32.dll hosts one of the largest icon collections in Windows 10.

To get the complete list of dlls check out this [article](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/where-find-most-windows-10s-native-icons).